# EXT JS Application Design Advice

Tags: extjs4

in need of EXT JS application design advice. here is a diagram of what I have so far:

http://screencast.com/t/RCdve5dO2

I have a window, with a toolbar. On the tb there are 3 menus, a button and a store to track some info. the window itself is an image which changes upon button click based on the values of the menus. i have a menu handler for this.

this all works fine and well with one window.

the issue i'm having is I can create multiple instances of the window on a drop event (drag from tree on the left). when more than one window is open there is some sort of menu collision. the menus on one window break when select an item on the other window. like so:

http://screencast.com/t/bbJ8RjlQK1b1

it seem all instances of the window seem to be sharing the same handler, or perhaps each window shares the same menu instance? i will need to investigate.

my question:

so taking a step back, the requirement is that each of the duplicate windows (and there could be many) must operate independently. from a design perspective, whats the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess, you are defining objects or arrays for the component class outside of the initComponent function.

Can you post your code please?

You should declare all non-primatives inside initComponent like this:

```
Ext.define('SomeComponent', {

  extend:'SomeOtherComponent',

  title:'a string is a primitive type. so is a number',

  initComponent: function(){

    Ext.applyIf(this, {
      someNonPrimitiveProperty:{ text:'arrays and objects are non-primitive' }
    });

    this.callParent(arguments); //always call this

  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for initComponent. I did read this on Sencha forums.  But I was looking for higher level architecture opinions.

Comment: in general, try to share nothing between components, including their stores and model instances. 

you could purposely share models, but don't do that by default.